# The RISC-V Rocket-Chip cycle-accurate C++ emulator fails with a "std::bad_alloc" error

Tags: riscv

I've tried to test RISC-V Rocket-Chip cycle-accurate C++ emulator by obeying the instructions on [github](https://github.com/ucb-bar/rocket-chip#how) and I got errors as shown below.

```
g++ -O1 -std=c++11 -I/home/iorivur/src/scala/riscv/toolchain/include -I/home/iorivur/src/test/rocket-chip/csrc -I/home/iorivur/src/test/rocket-chip/dramsim2 -o emulator-D
efaultCPPConfig emulator.o mm.o mm_dramsim2.o Top.DefaultCPPConfig.o  -L/home/iorivur/src/scala/riscv/toolchain/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/iorivur/src/scala/riscv/toolchain/lib
 -L. -ldramsim -lfesvr -lpthread
./emulator-DefaultCPPConfig +dramsim +max-cycles=100000000 +verbose +loadmem=output/rv64ui-p-add.hex none 2> output/rv64ui-p-add.out && [ $PIPESTATUS -eq 0 ]
./emulator-DefaultCPPConfig +dramsim +max-cycles=100000000 +verbose +loadmem=output/rv64ui-p-addi.hex none 2> output/rv64ui-p-addi.out && [ $PIPESTATUS -eq 0 ]
./emulator-DefaultCPPConfig +dramsim +max-cycles=100000000 +verbose +loadmem=output/rv64ui-p-amoadd_d.hex none 2> output/rv64ui-p-amoadd_d.out && [ $PIPESTATUS -eq 0 ]
./emulator-DefaultCPPConfig +dramsim +max-cycles=100000000 +verbose +loadmem=output/rv64ui-p-amoadd_w.hex none 2> output/rv64ui-p-amoadd_w.out && [ $PIPESTATUS -eq 0 ]
./emulator-DefaultCPPConfig +dramsim +max-cycles=100000000 +verbose +loadmem=output/rv64ui-p-amoand_d.hex none 2> output/rv64ui-p-amoand_d.out && [ $PIPESTATUS -eq 0 ]
/bin/sh: line 1: 11307 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./emulator-DefaultCPPConfig +dramsim +max-cycles=100000000 +verbose +loadmem=output/rv64ui-p-amoadd_w.hex non
e 2> output/rv64ui-p-amoadd_w.out
/bin/sh: line 1: 11304 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./emulator-DefaultCPPConfig +dramsim +max-cycles=100000000 +verbose +loadmem=output/rv64ui-p-addi.hex none 2>
 output/rv64ui-p-addi.out
/bin/sh: line 1: 11305 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./emulator-DefaultCPPConfig +dramsim +max-cycles=100000000 +verbose +loadmem=output/rv64ui-p-add.hex none 2> 
output/rv64ui-p-add.out
Makefile:71: recipe for target 'output/rv64ui-p-addi.out' failed
make: *** [output/rv64ui-p-addi.out] Error 134
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
Makefile:71: recipe for target 'output/rv64ui-p-add.out' failed
make: *** [output/rv64ui-p-add.out] Error 134
Makefile:71: recipe for target 'output/rv64ui-p-amoadd_w.out' failed
make: *** [output/rv64ui-p-amoadd_w.out] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 11311 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./emulator-DefaultCPPConfig +dramsim +max-cycles=100000000 +verbose +loadmem=output/rv64ui-p-amoand_d.hex non
e 2> output/rv64ui-p-amoand_d.out
Makefile:71: recipe for target 'output/rv64ui-p-amoand_d.out' failed
make: *** [output/rv64ui-p-amoand_d.out] Error 134
/bin/sh: line 1: 11306 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./emulator-DefaultCPPConfig +dramsim +max-cycles=100000000 +verbose +loadmem=output/rv64ui-p-amoadd_d.hex non
e 2> output/rv64ui-p-amoadd_d.out
Makefile:71: recipe for target 'output/rv64ui-p-amoadd_d.out' failed
make: *** [output/rv64ui-p-amoadd_d.out] Error 134
```

The contents of "output/rv64ui-p-amoadd_w.out" is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

I found the program has gone insane on `mm_t` initialization.

This code is gonna grab 4GB memory and if it fails, the program dies suddenly.

Answer (score 3):

As I edited above, I found the program has gone insane on mm_t initialization.
This code is gonna grap 4GB memory, and if it gone too bad than the code expect, then the program die suddenly.

I think this behavior and no mention on document is no good.

I will write a patch to catch this exception and to notify user sooner.

Thanks.